# unable drag the item to the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am using ember drag drop plugin in my ember-app:"ember install ember-drag-drop"
to drag the item from one place to another but i am unable to drop to the input field.

here is my code:

```
{{#draggable-object content=systemVariableInfo dragStartAction='myStartAction' dragEndAction='myEndAction'}}                    
{{item.name}}   
{{/draggable-object}}
```

controller::

```
myStartAction: function(content) {
        console.log("content"+content);
     //Content is the same as the content parameter set above
    },
    myEndAction: function(content) {
      //Content is the same as the content parameter set above
    },
```

how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the target into `draggable-object-target`:

```
<div>
    {{#each items as |item|}}
    {{#draggable-object content=item}}                    
      {{item.name}}
    {{/draggable-object}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
<br>
<form>
{{#draggable-object-target action="onDrop"}}
  {{input type="text" placeholder="drop here" value=inputValue}}
{{/draggable-object-target}}
</form>
```

See [Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c95aed06c1e7b7b7f83ad8ae46202f88?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).